# PHPWORD Laravel Can't Use HTML Value

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

I'm using Laravel 8 and want to use [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

This is my controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
class CWord extends Controller{
public function CreateWord()
{
$desc1 = DB::table('dummy')->where('id',1)->first();
$path = "assets_file/";
$my_template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(public_path($path.'helloWorld.docx'));
$my_template->setValue('name', $desc1->content);     
try{
$my_template->saveAs(public_path($path.'user_1.docx'));
}catch (Exception $e){
        //handle exception
}
return response()->download(public_path($path.'user_1.docx'));
}
}
```

I Use PHP Word Template and want to call value from the database

But Value in Database is HTML script

```
<span><span>KODE<span>:&nbsp;02.01.03.00</span></span><span>LAMA PROSES<span>:&nbsp;10 HARI KERJA</span></span><span>KATEGORI PROSEDUR<span><br>:&nbsp;IZIN TANPA RETRIBUSI NAMUN TETAP SURVEY</span></span>
```

docx file its successful download, but nothing value

When I test using test value like this

```
$my_template->setValue('name', "Andi");
```

value exists, this problem only fails when using HTML value.

Comment: I'd suggest debugging this part - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/TemplateProcessor.php#L317, add some var_dump and exits.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1wfwdi9 its get a value, but not show in doc file